# Environment.GetCommandLineArgs - why is it a method? Why not a property?

Tags: .net, methods, properties, environment-variables

I'm trying to understand the design considerations of the team that created the method [`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx).

It could have been a static property, very much like `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`. After all, the returned value should not change once available. So it's more like a property of the current running process.

I know that any property in .NET is a syntactic sugar to getter/setter methods. But that's the exact reason for using a property rather than an explicit getter method.

Or maybe there is there something I'm missing here?

What do you think?

Comment: The BCL team respected a semantic distinction between properties and methods. Properties are only used when the programmer can/should consider a call to them equivalent to accessing a field. In this case, `GetCommandLineArgs` doesn't work that way, so it's a method. Think of it as retrieving or calculating the value anew each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect it's because it makes a copy of the array each time you call it. For example, consider this program:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] argsCopy = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        args[0] = "x";

        // 0 is the command in this case
        argsCopy[1] = "y";

        string[] argsCopy2 = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        Console.WriteLine(argsCopy2[1]);
    }
}
```

If you run this with "test original" it will still print out "original".

So when you say:

> After all, the returned value should not change once available.

Actually, it will return a different value (a new array reference) on every call, precisely because arrays are *always* mutable.

Comment: Hmmmm.. good point. I guess you're right, it should be a **copy** of the original array, hence a new array for each call.

Comment: Which is why I think [`IReadOnlyList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should have been in the Framework a long time ago and used a lot instead of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, methods are used for actions (doing something). So calling a method will mean you're going through some big(ger) piece of logic, like a calculation or a call to a database-repository. And properties are basically just for getting or setting variables. If you want a person's name you're going to have a property 'Name' and call it like person.Name and not person.Name(). But if you want the age of the person and you only have the birthyear, you'll probably have a method GetAge() with basic logic for the calculation of the age. Perhaps I'm completely wrong here but my understanding is that methods are used for bigger chunks of code and logic whereas properties are used for (more) simply setting and getting values.